# rtabmap_ros: how it works?

Tags: slam, navigation, 3dmapping, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm using the [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) package in my project in order to build 3D maps from my recorded bags files.
The package works very well and I'm able to obtain accurate maps.

I've read all the documents about the [RTAB-Map](http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/) algorithm and also the [articles](https://introlab.3it.usherbrooke.ca/mediawiki-introlab/images/e/eb/Labbe14-IROS.pdf) wrote by Mathieu Labbé.
The problem is that I still can't understand how mathematically the closed loop detection works and how the 3D map is built.

Is there any document which I can read in order to understand how the algorithm mathematically works?
Can you help me please?

Thank you a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245873/rtabmap_ros:-how-it-works?/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For loop closure detection, see this [paper](https://introlab.3it.usherbrooke.ca/mediawiki-introlab/images/b/bc/TRO2013.pdf). The code follows pretty much the algorithms shown.

For the 3D map, we simply assemble point clouds of each node in the graph, as described loosely in the [paper](https://introlab.3it.usherbrooke.ca/mediawiki-introlab/images/e/eb/Labbe14-IROS.pdf) your referred:

> Fig. 9 shows the resulting global map by assembling  the  RGB-D  point  clouds  from  the  Kinect  using the optimized poses of the graph.

Search **Graph-Based SLAM** to learn more about the map structure used in RTAB-Map.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3